# Custom compiled Nginx with ngx_pagespeed in CentOS 7 wont start

Tags: centos, nginx, vps

Since PageSpeed must be compiled along with Nginx, and I don't like the way instructions are in the Google page, I decided to follow [another](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/speed-up-nginx-using-ngx_pagespeed-on-a-centos-6-vps/) great one.

Anyway, I did everything there. And when I get to the `service nginx restart`, I got a FAILED error:

```
Restarting nginx (via systemctl):  Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

`systemctl status nginx.service -l` output:

```
systemctl status nginx.service -l
nginx.service - SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar 2015-03-17 12:59:03 EDT; 1min 21s ago
  Process: 19716 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

mar 17 12:59:03 alemany.me systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server...
mar 17 12:59:03 alemany.me systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
mar 17 12:59:03 alemany.me systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server.
mar 17 12:59:03 alemany.me systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

`journalctl -xn` output:

```
journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at mar 2015-03-17 11:09:37 EDT, end at mar 2015-03-17 13:05:46 EDT. --
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[19761]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx: Exec fo
-- Subject: Process /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned while executing this process is 8.
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) revers
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
lines 1-25...skipping...
-- Logs begin at mar 2015-03-17 11:09:37 EDT, end at mar 2015-03-17 13:05:46 EDT. --                                                                                                           
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server...                                                          
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun with start-up                                                                                                                                         
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                                                                                                             
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.                                                                                                                                                   
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[19761]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx: Exec format error                                                                              
-- Subject: Process /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx could not be executed                                                                                                                               
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                                                                                                             
-- The process /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx could not be executed and failed.                                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                                                                                                             
-- The error number returned while executing this process is 8.                                                                                                                                
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203                                                                                           
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server.                                                     
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
mar 17 13:03:39 alemany.me systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
mar 17 13:05:46 alemany.me systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
mar 17 13:05:46 alemany.me systemd[19766]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx: Exec format error
-- Subject: Process /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned while executing this process is 8.
mar 17 13:05:46 alemany.me systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
mar 17 13:05:46 alemany.me systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Nginx is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
```

I thought maybe something was listening to port 80. Here's the "netstat" output:

```
netstat -punta
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      899/master          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      747/sshd            
tcp        0     36 128.199.42.29:22        200.55.154.30:38580     ESTABLISHED 9536/sshd: root@pts 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      899/master          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      747/sshd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33440           0.0.0.0:*                           344/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           344/avahi-daemon: r
```

Anyway, I have no idea why is happening that. I installed that on a CentOS 7 VPS which is in zero state. Nothing else is installed there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the init script is executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Also check the selinux status. You can temporarily disable it by issuing the following command:

```
setenforce 0
```